# cv2.polylines: color gets ignored

Tags: python, opencv, polyline

In the second to last line of the following code I am drawing a polyline and specify the color as black `(0,0,0)`. Yet the linews are drawn in white. Anyone can explain me why?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

# helper function
def showImage(img, title):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle(title)
    plt.imshow(img)


# read and show test image
img = mpimg.imread('undistorted.jpg')
showImage(img, "undistorted")


# source points
top_left = [427,564]
top_right = [873,564]
bottom_right = [1074,690]
bottom_left = [249,690]
pts = np.array([top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left])

cv2.polylines(img,np.int32([pts]),True,(0,0,0), 5) # line color given as (0,0,0) = black, but drawn as white?
showImage(img, "preview")
```

This is the output:
[image]

This is the input image I use:
[image]

Thanks for any hints on this!

Comment: Which versions are the libraries you're using? I can't reproduce this with OpenCV 2.4.11 or 3.1.0 together with matplotlib 1.5.1. I get a black rectangle, not a white one.

Comment: I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 and matplotlib 2.0.0. I meanwhile found it it has to do with the image. It works as expected on another image, even on the input image I uploaded here, which is actually not (on bitlevel/the file) identical to the one I uploaded.

Comment: Update: my original input image has 32 bit colors (I actually don't know why), maybe that was the problem.